# In Cypher, determine the type (label) of objects connecting a referenced object

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm working on a dependency analysis tool and I've come up with the following Cypher query which expresses SCHEMAs who own objects that reference eachother, inferring the dependency from schema to schema, like follows:

```
MATCH (sourceSchema:SCHEMA)-[:OWNS]->(objectOwnedBySource)-[:REFERENCES*..]->(objectOwnedByTarget)<-[:OWNS]-(targetSchema:SCHEMA)
WHERE sourceSchema.name <> targetSchema.name
WITH sourceSchema, targetSchema
ORDER BY targetSchema.name
RETURN sourceSchema.name AS schema,
collect(distinct targetSchema.name) AS dependsOn
ORDER BY sourceSchema.name
```

The above query returns a rather awesome list of schemas and their dependencies which looks something like this:

```
schema  dependsOn
FOO     [BAR, BAZ, PUBLIC, SYS]
BAR     [SYS]
BAZ     [PUBLIC, SYS]
(etc)
```

With some help, I also managed to create a query that gives me a list of types (labels) and their count per schema in the graph:

```
MATCH (sourceSchema:SCHEMA)-[:OWNS]->(objectOwnedBySource)
RETURN DISTINCT sourceSchema.name AS schema,
filter(x IN (labels(objectOwnedBySource)) WHERE NOT x="ENTITY")[0] AS type,
count(*) AS count 
ORDER BY schema,type
```

The output from the above looks something like:

```
schema  type      count
FOO     TABLE     14
FOO     SYNONYM   1
BAR     FUNCTION  3
```

My question is: how do I somehow combine this and get the count of labels causing the schema to schema dependency? My intent is:

```
Schema           DependsOnSchema   ThroughLabelOnReferencedObject   Count
FOO              BAR               TABLE                            101
FOO              BAR               VIEW                             10
FOO              BAZ               TABLE                            6
(etc)
```

Bonus points for a separate counter for both incoming and outgoing references :-). Thanks for any pointers in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I came up with:

```
MATCH (sourceSchema:SCHEMA)-[:OWNS]->(objectOwnedBySource)-[:REFERENCES*..]->(objectOwnedByTarget)<-[:OWNS]-(targetSchema)
WHERE sourceSchema <> targetSchema
RETURN DISTINCT sourceSchema.name AS source,
filter(x IN (labels(objectOwnedBySource)) WHERE NOT x="ENTITY")[0] AS sourceType,
targetSchema.name AS target,
filter(x IN (labels(objectOwnedByTarget)) WHERE NOT x="ENTITY")[0] AS targetType,
count(*) AS references
ORDER BY source,sourceType,target,targetType
```

Which gives me:

```
source    sourceType    target    targetType    references
FOO       TABLE         BAR       SEQUENCE      3
BAR       FUNCTION      BAZ       PACKAGE       10
(etc)
```